# How to smooth numbers from a file as many times as wanted in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, smoothing

I'm trying to create a code that will open a file with a list of numbers in it and then take those numbers and smooth them as many times as the user wants. I have it opening and reading the file, but it will not transpose the numbers. In this format it gives this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'float'. I also need to figure out how to make it transpose the numbers the amount of times the user asks it to. The list of numbers I used in my .txt file is [3, 8, 5, 7, 1].

Here is exactly what I am trying to get it to do:

Ask the user for a filename

Read all floating point data from file into a list

Ask the user how many smoothing passes to make

Display smoothed results with two decimal places

Use functions where appropriate

Algorithm:
Never change the first or last value
Compute new values for all other values by averaging the value with its two neighbors

Here is what I have so far:

```
filename = raw_input('What is the filename?: ')
inFile = open(filename)
data = inFile.read()
print data
data2 = data[:]
print data2
data2[1]=(data[0]+data[1]+data[2])/3.0
print data2
data2[2]=(data[1]+data[2]+data[3])/3.0
print data2
data2[3]=(data[2]+data[3]+data[4])/3.0
print data2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly don't want to be manually indexing the list items. Instead, use a loop:

```
data2 = data[:]
for i in range(1, len(data)-1):
    data2[i] = sum(data[i-1:i+2])/3.0
data = data2
```

You can then put that code inside another loop, so that you smooth repeatedly:

```
smooth_steps = int(raw_input("How many times do you want to smooth the data?"))
for _ in range(smooth_steps):
    # code from above goes here
```

Note that my code above assumes that you have read numeric values into the `data` list. However, the code you've shown doesn't do this. You simply use `data = inFile.read()` which means `data` is a string. You need to actually parse your file in some way to get a list of numbers.

In your immediate example, where the file contains a Python formatted list literal, you could use `eval` (or `ast.literal_eval` if you wanted to be a bit safer). But if this data is going to be used by any other program, you'll probably want a more widely supported format, like CSV, JSON or YAML (all of which have parsers available in Python).

Comment: The loop really helped, I'm just not sure what you mean by parsing my file and how to do that. Also where would I put eval or ast.literal_eval? (It doesn't like that there is no definition for ast in that one) I'm new at this.

Comment: I'm also getting this error when I run it: data2[i] = sum(data[i-1:i+2])/3.0

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: That error comes from the lack of parsing. If your file contains the text `[3, 8, 5, 7, 1]`, replace `data = inFile.read()` with `data = eval(inFile.read())`. Or import the `ast` module and use `ast.literal_eval` instead of the builtin `eval` function (which might do bad things if your file contained malicious data).

Comment: How do I incorporate a for loop at the end to make the output display the smoothed results with two decimal places?